# Why is socket.post() slow as compared to socket.emit() [Its too slow]

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, sails.js

I was building a resumeable file uploader in Nodejs. First I implemented it in raw Node.js using `socket.emit()` then I ported it to Sails.js and made calls to sails controllers using `socket.post()` from the client. I figured out that implementation using `socket.emit()` was much faster then the one using `socket.post()`. Can any body tell me why..??

Answer (score 2):

Socket.post doesn't *really* exist. It's a convenience method added by sails in `sails.io.js`. It allows you to fake a POST request over sockets that goes through routing etc allowing you to use your restful setup over sockets.

Using emit just emits an event over that specific socket connection on which you can react server side. It doesn't go through routing unless you specifically ask it to. [Here's a link to the specific line in 0.9](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/blob/v0.9.16/bin/boilerplates/assets/js/sails.io.js#L132).

So, recap, `socket.post()` does magic, whereas `socket.emit()` doesn't, and simply uses the emit method as supplied by socket.io.

Comment: Does sails.io.js create a new connection on every new socket.post()..? If not why it is slow as compared to socket.emit().

Comment: It does not. The connection stays. It's slower because it does more processing, both client and server-side (think: blueprints, routing, logging etc).

Comment: I am still not getting what I want.. Why is socket.post() hell too slow as compared to socket.emit()..?